# how to redirect and show error validateion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

good day,
I  new in laravel Framework  and I face this  two problems : -
first one
 I want to redirect to my page after 2 seconds automatically.
the second one
I make custom function call (is exist ) 
if this function returns true data I want to print "name exist before " but the problem here is form was rested when this function returns true and print message.
how to prevent form resetting from inputs value?
here is my code

controller code

```
enter code here
public function add(Request $request)

{
        // start add
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['add']))
        {
            // start validatio array
        $validationarray=$this->validate($request,[
            //'name'  =>'required|max:25|min:1|unique:mysql2.products,name|alpha',
            'name'  =>'required|alpha',
            'price' =>'required|numeric',

            ]);
                // check name is exist

            if(true !=dBHelper::isExist('mysql2','products','`status`=? AND `deleted` =? AND `name`=?',array(1,1,$validationarray['name'])))
            {

                $product=new productModel();
                // start add
                $product->name=$request->input('name');
                $product->save();
                $add=$product->id;
                $poducten=new productEnModel();
                $poducten->id_product=$add;
                $poducten->name=$request->input('name');
                $poducten->price=$request->input('price');
                $poducten->save();
                $dataview['message']='data addes';




            }else{
                $dataview['message']='name is exist before';
            }

        }
    }
    $dataview['pagetitle']="add product geka";
    return view('productss.add',$dataview);
}
```

this is my routes

```
Route::get('/products/add',"produtController@add");
    Route::post('/products/add',"produtController@add");
```

this is my view

```
@extends('layout.header')
@section('content')
    @if(isset($message))
        {{$message}}
    @endif

    @if(count($errors)>0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{$error}}</li>

                  @endforeach

            </ul>

        </div>
        @endif

    <form role="form"  action="add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group{{$errors->has('name')?'has-error':''}}">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="{{Request::old('name')}}" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Employee Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" value="{{Request::old('price')}}" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Employee Email Address">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question.
Instead of using {{ Request::old('price') }} use {{ old('price') }} 
This should retrieve the form data after page was reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below the code for error display in view page

```
   $validator = Validator::make($params, $req_params);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      $errors = $validator->errors()->toArray();
      return Redirect::to($web_view_path)->with('errors', $errors);
    }
```

You want to automatically redirect to another page submit the form using ajax and use below the settimeout menthod.

```
setTimeout(function(){  // Here mentioned the redirect query }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use $request instead of $_POST
if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        if(isset($request['add']))
        {
            // start validatio array
        $validationarray=$this->validate($request,[
            //'name'  =>'required|max:25|min:1|unique:mysql2.products,name|alpha',
            'name'  =>'required|alpha',
            'price' =>'required|numeric',

            ]);
                // check name is exist
```